# Flip box on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css

The below codes defines boxes that flips when any area of the box is touched or clicked but I would rather this function was specific to a button instead so that instead of clicking on any area of the box to achieve a flip, a button is used instead. How can I tweak this code to achieve this.

I want the button within these divs to be responsible for the flip function rather than having to click on any area of the box and I would equally like to achieve this possibility in all cases.

```
cards.forEach(card => {
  card.addEventListener('click', function() {
    card.classList.toggle('is-flipped');
  });
})
```

```
.flip-box {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip-box-front,
.flip-box-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-box-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-box-back {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card.is-flipped {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```
<div class="flip-box">

<div class="card">
<div class="flip-box-front"> 
<h2>Front Side</h2> 
<p> some text </p>
<p> some text </p>
<button> click to flip </button>
</div> 

<div class="flip-box-back"> 
<h2>Back Side</h2>
<p> some text </p> 
<p> some text </p> 
<button> click to flip </button>
</div>

</div> 

<br/>
<div class="card">
<div class="flip-box-front"> 
<h2>Front Side</h2> 
<p> some text </p>
<p> some text </p>
<button> click to flip </button>
</div> 

<div class="flip-box-back"> 
<h2>Back Side</h2>
<p> some text </p> 
<p> some text </p> 
<button> click to flip </button>
</div>

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide working code snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that all the `button` tags are "click to flip" and:

```js
cards = someRoot.querySelectorAll(".card");
```

you can modify the code to:

```js
cards.forEach(card => {
  // For each card
  card.querySelectorAll("div > button").forEach(btn => {
    // For each button on the card sides
    btn.addEventListener("click", ev => {
      // Toggle the "is-flipped" class
      ev.target.parentElement.parentElement.classList.toggle("is-flipped");
    });
  });
});
```

Full demo:

```js
// Get all cards
var cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
cards.forEach(card => {
  // For each card
  card.querySelectorAll("div > button").forEach(btn => {
    // For each button on the card sides
    btn.addEventListener("click", ev => {
      // Toggle the "is-flipped" class of the button parent's parent
      ev.target.parentElement.parentElement.classList.toggle("is-flipped");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.flip-box {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip-box-front,
.flip-box-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-box-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-box-back {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card.is-flipped {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-box">

  <div class="card">
    <div class="flip-box-front">
      <h2>Front Side</h2>
      <p> some text </p>
      <p> some text </p>
      <button> click to flip </button>
    </div>

    <div class="flip-box-back">
      <h2>Back Side</h2>
      <p> some text </p>
      <p> some text </p>
      <button> click to flip </button>
    </div>

  </div>

  <br/>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="flip-box-front">
      <h2>Front Side</h2>
      <p> some text </p>
      <p> some text </p>
      <button> click to flip </button>
    </div>

    <div class="flip-box-back">
      <h2>Back Side</h2>
      <p> some text </p>
      <p> some text </p>
      <button> click to flip </button>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Good effort on the answer @Plantt !

Comment: Thank you @Plantt. what  happens if button exist inside a div say <div style="text-align: center;"> <button> click to flip </button></div>

Comment: @Dwin You need to add `.parentElement` as many times as the button is a child of an element. Example, if the code was `<div><div><div><div><div><button>Click to flip</button></div></div></div></div></div>`, you'd add `elm.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement`.